# Call external program using CPI Anchor way

Tags: anchor, solana-program, cpi

i'm working with CPI. I followed this example and it worked ok (https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/CPIs.html). But in this example it adds a dependency to a program that it have created (puppet), i was wondering how can i do a CPI call to a program which is not mine, i mean, a program that has been already deployed by someone else. should it be possible, right?

In the example it adds a local dependency using path attribute
puppet = { path = "../puppet", features = ["cpi"]}
it would not be possible if i'm not the owner of the Program i want to call

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that's totally possible! All you need is a way to create instructions for the other program.

For example, if you want to call into the SPL token program, you need to import the library with the instructions, so that in your program, you can do something like:

```
use spl_token::instruction::transfer
...

// in your program
let instruction = transfer(...).unwrap();
invoke(instruction, &[...])?;
```